# How can I classify the following conditional sentences?

Tags: conditionals

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veTo6eWJQrM). It classifies conditionals as follows:

[image]

I see that these variations are missing:

1. (Present → Past) *If I say something, I destroyed everything.*
2. (Present Perfect → Present Perfect) *If I have done it, I have done it for you.*
3. (Present Perfect → Future) *If I have done it, I will do it again.*
4. (Present → Present perfect) *If I eat pizza, I have also eaten cheese.*
5. (Past → Past) *If I bought anything, I bought that with my own money.*
6. (Past → Past Perfect) *If I did it last year, I had done it perfectly.*
7. (Past Perfect → Past Perfect) *If I had done that, I had done that for you.*
8. (Past Future → Past future) *If I would eat meat, I would not be a vegan anymore.*
9. (Future → Future) *If I will do it, I will do it myself.*
10. (Future → Present) *If I will tell him, I tell him on his face.*

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

How can I classify these conditional sentences into 0th, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd conditionals?

Comment: 1 doesn’t work at all.  2 Ok 3 Ok. 4 Marginal, but No. 5 Ok But s/that/it/ 6 No. 7 No. 8 Ok. 9 9 Ok (but not crazy about the example)  10 No (also “on his face???”)

Comment: There's  no such thing as "numbered" conditionals.

Comment: This is utterly ridiculous. Nobody except the students who use this textbook will ever understand this terminology; and it looks like even they get confused and/or overenthusiastic.

Comment: @JohnLawler, which text book are you talking about? There is no text book. I drew the diagram myself on the basis of the video.

Comment: @tchrist, what do you mean? I found numbered conditionals in grammar books and in Wikipedia also.

Comment: @Jim, brother, kindly post an answer. Kindly explain why.

Comment: @user366312, the "grammar books" that you mention are textbooks. They are full of misinformation that has been presented as correct. Most of it is useless, like classifying conditionals. If you give them numbers, that makes people feel like there's a comfortable regularity that can be learned by rote. Unfortunately, not true.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I haven't mentioned any "book". I mentioned only a video.